# CMTS (DOCSIS 3.0) with CGN (CGNat)

Tags: vlan, nat, isp, docsis

For a new project/building I am working with the CMTS model MA5633-XB10 by Huawei.

The usual way is done by implementing two DHCP servers in the same VLAN, from which the CPE gets the private IP address and the configuration file at first. After downloading the configuration file and rebooting the cable modems are being diverted to the second DHCP, where they receive a public IP address.

As we have an existing A10 Networks CGN enviroment (for DSL users), I would like to conserve the use of public IP addresses and instead let the cable modems rather get an IP address from the CGN pool.

Does anyone know, how this is to be done or if that is possible with a CMTS/DOCSIS scenario, at all?

Thanks a lot and best regards.

Comment: Can't you just configure the pool to hand out CGN addresses and connect the VLAN to the router?

Comment: Well, that might collide with the given out addresses by the A10 devices. Also, they are in a different VLAN. I guess, I have to consider some routing there.